# 401 on Ajax calls with latest Chrome (64)

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I'm logging into a site with what I think is Basic Authentication on IIS. Then I hit a date picker on the page and I get a 401 auth error. Works on Safari/Firefox and it worked on Chrome version 63. Anything change? Inspect tells me I'm passing https://null:null@[hostname] which seems wrong. Chrome version is 64.0.3282.167. Firefox does not seem to attempt to put the user/pass in the request, it's just hitting https://[hostname]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in Chrome 64. Resolved in 65 Beta if you need it.